# boto3: cognito-idp painfully slow

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm new with AWS Python SDK and I'm using boto3 in a script that creates a user in a Cognito user pool but it takes too long and I don't know why

```python
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    'cognito-idp',
    region_name='us-east-1'
)

response = client.admin_create_user(
    UserPoolId='us-east-1_ID_OF_MY_POOL',
    Username='email@gmail.com',
    UserAttributes=[
        {"Name": "email","Value": "email@gmail.com"},
        { "Name": "email_verified", "Value": "true" }
    ]
)

print(response)
```

This simple script, specially the `admin_create_user` (and also the login or sign up methods, I already tried with those) can take more than 1 minute

I use a Macbook Pro with M1 Pro.

```
boto3 version: 1.23.0
botocore version: 1.26.0
python version: 3.9.7
```

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior too, with `cognito-idp` and `ssm`. Is the behavior consistent? And have you had any success in diagnosing or fixing it?